# Get CSS animation like SVG animated path

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

Is it possible to get the following animation that I created with an SVG path with CSS only?

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
svg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.path {
    animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z" stroke-dasharray="2042 300" stroke-dashoffset="2342" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccqxcnw0/2/)

Comment: No, as CSS does not support this attribute or has any equivalent attribute for its elements. Also, you are using `@-webkit-keyframes` but just a `animation` attribute, which didn't work for me.

Comment: What I meant was instead of using an SVG path, creating it with only CSS

Comment: And what I meant is that CSS does not have this kind of option and no good way to mimic it. Strokes are full and have no offsets in CSS so you cannot do this in CSS with standard HTML elements, only with SVG. Don't get me wrong, you might be able to fake it with multiple elements and nesting but I think that your SVG solution is probably optimal for the effect you want.

Comment: It's certainly possible, take a look at what's possible with [a single div](http://a.singlediv.com/). Although something is possible, it might not be an advisable route to take. Could you elaborate on why you would prefer a CSS over SVG?

Comment: I'm having some problems with getting the path to act responsive, that's why I was looking for alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure SVG is the way to go here, I think using css for an animation like this will have far more pitfalls then using SVG.

Nonetheless are you able to achieve a similar animation using CSS, A mayor downside is that this requires a fixed aspect ratio for the element the snake is circling. Otherwise the animation will  vary in speed. Another mayor downside is that it requires the background colour of the surrounding elements to be static.

This solution uses a square which moves along the outer edge, giving the impression of a moving border.

```css
.div-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
}
.snake {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1vw;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.snake:before {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  animation: around linear 10s infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1
}
.snake.red:before {
  background-color: red;
}
@keyframes around {
  0% {
    top: calc(-4vw - 1px);
    left: calc(100% - 4vw + 1px);
  }
  25% {
    top: calc(100% - 4vw + 1px);
    left: calc(100% - 4vw + 1px);
  }
  50% {
    top: calc(100% - 4vw + 1px);
    left: calc(-4vw - 1px);
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(-4vw - 1px);
    left: calc(-4vw - 1px);
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(-4vw - 1px);
    left: calc(100% - 4vw + 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="snake">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div class="snake red">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Honestly I would stick with SVG.

Comment: yeah I think it would be the best as well thanks anyway and still great effort in making it with CSS!